# arduino with ethernet shield + android

Tags: android, arduino

Is it possible to connect the arduino to the 3G network from the android when enabling the hotspot using the ethernet shield?
if yes, please tell me how, if not, what can i do to connect the arduino with an android phone other than using Bluetooth or the USB cable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you enable a "hotspot" on an android device, it creates a wifi network that other devices can connect to. These devices can then access the 3G network through the phone.

If the ethernet shield that you're referring to has Wifi capabilities, then yes this is possible. I know that Wifi shields do exist for arduino, but you can't just use any old ethernet shield.

Comment: Yes, that is what it is doing. Sorry. I will correct my answer.